# Specializing std::optional

Tags: c++, std, template-specialization, c++14

Will it be possible to specialize `std::optional` for user-defined types? If not, is it too late to propose this to the standard?

My use case for this is an integer-like class that represents a value within a range. For instance, you could have an integer that lies somewhere in the range [0, 10]. Many of my applications are sensitive to even a single byte of overhead, so I would be unable to use a non-specialized `std::optional` due to the extra `bool`. However, a specialization for `std::optional` would be trivial for an integer that has a range smaller than its underlying type. We could simply store the value `11` in my example. This should provide no space or time overhead over a non-optional value.

Am I allowed to create this specialization in `namespace std`?

Comment: In that case, define your own optional class. It is not that hard to do.

Comment: But it would be much nicer for the users of my class to just be able to type `std::optional<whatever type they want>`, rather than having to remember that my type is special and should be stored in its own optional class for maximum efficiency.

Comment: If your type's usage is heavily dependent on it having a specified size, degree of efficiency or other such constraints, then it ___is___ special and it ___should___ be handled by its own/related facilities. C++ offers, by design, _very_ little guarantees about specific requirements for data types beyond what you have with eg.: `uint32_fast_t` within its standard utilities.

Comment: I disagree. The whole point of using C++ over C is that it gives you better abstractions with zero cost. The semantics of an overloaded optional would be identical. The code to use it would be identical. Why should I make my users use a separate class when there are no technical (other than the restriction in the standard on putting things in namespace std) reasons that they have to do so?

Comment: It would be as if C++ made you use a special `fast_multiply` function if you wanted performance from multiplication that you use for `short`, but the regular old `operator *` was there just to trip you up in case you accidentally use it. And when my users are trying to use a "generic integer type" in template code that could be my class or it could be a built-in integer, should they be expected to write a `the_optional_I_mean_to_use` alias template to pick the correct one, even though there is no reason they would ever want the default version?

Comment: The semantics may be identical, but changes in the internals could be pervasive. When discussing `optional<bool>`, the problem was that if one wanted to give access to the "contained" `bool`, which when optimizing via a `uint8_least_t` _doesn't exist_, one'd have to either reinterpret-cast a reference type and summon UB when the reference is used to write (a no-no as I was explained) or set up a proxy class to deliver the value, à-la-`vector<bool>`. None very charming options. I can see the smarter minds being able to solve it, the question is is it worth the hassle?

Comment: It is true that the specialization would need compiler magic for `optional<bool>`, but not `optional<tribool>`, which is the example I gave in comment to your answer. It would typically be implemented with some `enum` with an underlying type of `char` or similar typedef. You would simply add an additional state to the `enum` that can only be set by `optional`, and there really would be no way to tell the difference (other than `sizeof` returning `1` instead of `2`). So to bring it back to my follow-up question, is it too late to propose allowing specializations?

Comment: If you want to know if it is too late to propose, I would suggest checking the [ISO c++ Proposal Forums](http://www.isocpp.org/forums) where several things like these are thrown in. I would say it's not too late - one thing that eg.: contiguous storage guarantee for `string` or `vector` and proposals such as `dynarray` teaches us is that even the masterminds behind the language can forget very useful to have niceties (and the fixes can be very well welcome).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The general rule in 17.6.4.2.1 [namespace.std]/1 applies:

> A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace `std` only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly
>   prohibited.

So I would say it's allowed.

N.B. `optional` will not be part of the C++14 standard, it will be included in a separate Technical Specification on library fundamentals, so there is time to change the rule if my interpretation is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

If you are after a library that efficiently packs the value and the "no-value" flag into one memory location, I recommend looking at [compact_optional](https://github.com/akrzemi1/compact_optional). It does exactly this.

It does not specialize `boost::optional` or `std::experimental::optional` but it can wrap them inside, giving you a uniform interface, with optimizations where possible and a fallback to 'classical' optional where needed.

Comment: The author (same as answer's) deprecated the library and replaced it with https://github.com/akrzemi1/markable

Answer (score 2):

I've asked about the same thing, regarding specializing `optional<bool>` and `optional<tribool>` among other examples, to only use one byte. While the "legality" of doing such things was not under discussion, I do think that one should not, in theory, be allowed to specialize `optional<T>` in contrast to eg.: hash (which is explicitly allowed).

I don't have the logs with me but part of the rationale is that the interface treats access to the data as access to a pointer or reference, meaning that if you use a different data structure in the internals, some of the invariants of access might change; not to mention providing the interface with access to the data might require something like `reinterpret_cast<(some_reference_type)>`. Using a `uint8_t` to store a optional-bool, for example, would impose several extra requirements on the interface of `optional<bool>` that are different to the ones of `optional<T>`. What should the return type of `operator*` be, for example?

Basically, I'm guessing the idea is to avoid the whole **`vector<bool>` fiasco** again.

In your example, it might not be too bad, as the access type is still `your_integer_type&` (or pointer). But in that case, simply designing your integer type to allow for a "zombie" or "undetermined" value instead of relying on `optional<>` to do the job for you, with its extra overhead and requirements, might be the safest choice.

Comment: I understand why the standard committee would be hesitant to define their own specializations, but it seems that allowing it would be beneficial when it can be done without changing the interface. In the `tribool` case, the storage requirements are to ultimately contain `uint8_least_t`. You would then have one more value possible (0, 1, 2, and 3), but the value of "3" would only be settable when stored in an optional. Then users of the non-`optional` class know that it is a real instance without worrying about zombie states and users of `optional` wouldn't know that you made this optimization.

Comment: @DavidStone I started checking out doing this, and my leanings are to agree with this answer.  The problem is not the specialization or the namespace...it's the sematnics.  Trying to make a std::optional<T> without a T somewhere inside your specialization is going to be a problem.

Comment: Adding to my last paragraph I think I saw at some points in the C++ STD Proposals forum a proposal for a "degenerate enumeration type", basically a type interface for an integral type with a singular value marked out as "zombie" or "undetermined". That was about two months ago but might be worth to check it out.

Comment: @HostileFork: In my case, the specialized `std::optional<T>` would contain a `T` in it. In general, this could be done by way of a private constructor that sets up this special state (that is only used by optional) and declaring `std::optional<T>` a friend of your `T`.

Comment: @DavidStone Interestingly enough...after answering I did the same thing, here's an [unfinished blog article](http://blog.hostilefork.com/template-specialize-optional-or-not/) about it.  Instead of private construction I made `writeOptional` and a `testOptional` friend methods.  It's definitely a bit dodgy, though.  I'll finish that entry at some point, hopefully, but I want to get the code more finalized.

Answer (score 2):

### Make it easy to opt-in to space savings

I have decided that this is a useful thing to do, but a full specialization is a little more work than necessary (for instance, getting `operator=` correct).

I have posted on the Boost mailing list a way to simplify the task of specializing, especially when you only want to specialize some instantiations of a class template.

http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/optional-Specializing-optional-to-save-space-td4680362.html

My current interface involves a special tag type used to 'unlock' access to particular functions. I have creatively named this type `optional_tag`. Only `optional` can construct an `optional_tag`. For a type to opt-in to a space-efficient representation, it needs the following member functions:

- `T(optional_tag)` constructs an uninitialized value
- `initialize(optional_tag, Args && ...)` constructs an object when there may be one in existence already
- `uninitialize(optional_tag)` destroys the contained object
- `is_initialized(optional_tag)` checks whether the object is currently in an initialized state

By always requiring the optional_tag parameter, we do not limit any function signatures. This is why, for instance, we cannot use `operator bool()` as the test, because the type may want that operator for other reasons.

An advantage of this over some other possible methods of implementing it is that you can make it work with any type that can naturally support such a state. It does not add any requirements such as having a move constructor.

You can see a full code implementation of the idea at

https://bitbucket.org/davidstone/bounded_integer/src/8c5e7567f0d8b3a04cc98142060a020b58b2a00f/bounded_integer/detail/optional/optional.hpp?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

and for a class using the specialization:

https://bitbucket.org/davidstone/bounded_integer/src/8c5e7567f0d8b3a04cc98142060a020b58b2a00f/bounded_integer/detail/class.hpp?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

(lines 220 through 242)

### An alternative approach

This is in contrast to my previous implementation, which required users to specialize a class template. You can see the old version here:

https://bitbucket.org/davidstone/bounded_integer/src/2defec41add2079ba023c2c6d118ed8a274423c8/bounded_integer/detail/optional/optional.hpp

and

https://bitbucket.org/davidstone/bounded_integer/src/2defec41add2079ba023c2c6d118ed8a274423c8/bounded_integer/detail/optional/specialization.hpp

The problem with this approach is that it is simply more work for the user. Rather than adding four member functions, the user must go into a new namespace and specialize a template.

In practice, all specializations would have an `in_place_t` constructor that forwards all arguments to the underlying type. The `optional_tag` approach, on the other hand, can just use the underlying type's constructors directly.

In the specialize `optional_storage` approach, the user also has the responsibility of adding proper reference-qualified overloads of a value function. In the `optional_tag` approach, we already have the value so we do not have to pull it out.

`optional_storage` also required standardizing as part of the interface of optional two helper classes, only one of which the user is supposed to specialize (and sometimes delegate their specialization to the other).

### The difference between this and compact_optional

`compact_optional` is a way of saying "Treat this special sentinel value as the type being not present, almost like a NaN". It requires the user to know that the type they are working with has some special sentinel. An easily specializable `optional` is a way of saying "My type does not need extra space to store the not present state, but that state is not a normal value." It does not require anyone to know about the optimization to take advantage of it; everyone who uses the type gets it for free.

### The future

My goal is to get this first into boost::optional, and then part of the std::optional proposal. Until then, you can always use `bounded::optional`, although it has a few other (intentional) interface differences.

Comment: This would be amazing.  Is it too late for std::optional to be changed in future standards to support this strategy for efficient nullable types?

Comment: There has been some movement to add `tombtone_traits`. It has a slightly different interface than I mentioned in this answer, but I think I prefer that method. https://youtu.be/MWBfmmg8-Yo?t=2364 talks about it a bit. This approach has the advantage that it can also be used for hash tables (that sometimes need *two* distinct not-present states). There is nothing preventing std::optional from using this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how allowing or not allowing some particular bit pattern to represent the unengaged state falls under anything the standard covers.

If you were trying to convince a library vendor to do this, it would require an implementation, exhaustive tests to show you haven't inadvertently blown any of the requirements of optional (or accidentally invoked undefined behavior) and extensive benchmarking to show this makes a notable difference in real world (and not just contrived) situations.

Of course, you can do whatever you want to your own code.

Comment: My concern would be that I could not specialize templates in `namespace std` unless explicitly stated in the standard. It turns out that I got it backward, and that I can specialize any template unless prohibited (as long as I am doing so for a user-defined type).